# I`m trying to create array with value from activesheet (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create array with values from non-empty cells in range B6:B183 .  `array_articles = ActiveWorsheet.Range("B6:B183")` return empty array, so I'm trying to do this:

```
Sub set_price()
Dim articul_price() As String
Dim articul_bill As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim array_articles() As Variant
Dim array_unsorted() As String
Dim cell As Range
counter = 0
ReDim articul_price(0)
For Each cell In ActiveWorsheet.Range("B6:B183") ' error 424 Object required
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        array_unsorted(counter) = cell.Value
        ReDim Preserve array_unsorted(counter)
    Else
    'do nothing
    counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This code return

> error 424 Object required

[image: In Locals]

Comment: You have a typo in `ActiveWorsheet` (missing `k`) • But you can just do `array_unsorted = ActiveWorksheet.Range("B6:B183").Value` to load the range into an array (2-dimensional). If you want it 1-dimensional transpose the range: `array_unsorted = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ActiveWorksheet.Range("B6:B183").Value)`

Comment: I'm trying to write `Dim array_unsorted() As String
ReDim array_unsorted(0 To 200)
array_unsorted = ActiveWorksheet.Range("B6:B183").Value` but it still return empty array without data. `array_unsorted = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ActiveWorksheet.Range("B6:B183").Value)` return the same.

Comment: I posted it as an answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily load a range into an array (without a loop) use:

```
Dim array_unsorted As Variant 'must be variant!
array_unsorted = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheet").Range("B6:B183").Value '2-dimensional array
```

you can access the array with

```
Debug.Print array_unsorted(row, column) 'yes it has only 1 column but it is still there
Debug.Print array_unsorted(1, 1) 'first value
Debug.Print array_unsorted(2, 1) 'second value
```

or transpose it to make it 1-dimensional

```
array_unsorted = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheet").Range("B6:B183").Value) '1-dimensional
```

and you can access the array with

```
Debug.Print array_unsorted(i) 'this is 1-dimensional
Debug.Print array_unsorted(1) 'first value
Debug.Print array_unsorted(2) 'second value
```

Note that the transpose function has a limit of 65,536 rows. If you exceed them the rest will be truncated silently.

I recommend to avoid `ActiveWorksheet` (unless you write an add-in or the code is used for multiple worksheets). Use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheet")` to reference the worksheet by its name, which is more save and Excel won't run into errors.

Comment: Variant for 2-dimensional array worked, thanks. I suggest  that will be enough for this project.